# Removing all the columns of the data frame that have same values across all the rows

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a data frame like this :

```
1 NA 0.2 NA 1 2
2 NA 0.5 NA 1 6 
3 NA 0.7 NA 1 4 
4 NA 0.3 NA 1 4
```

I want to remove the columns that have same values across all the rows.i.e my data frame should look like this:

```
1 0.2 2
2 0.5 6 
3 0.7 4 
4 0.3 4
```

Is there an easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
dataf[sapply(dataf, function(x) length(unique(x))>1)]
```

Comment: How would you do this for rows?